# RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C returns error

Tags: python, docker

In the **Dockerfile** it has written like this:

```
FROM osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.6.3

RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y gnupg
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
```

While I built, it shows this error:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.13kB                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.6.3                                                                                     4.8s 
 => [auth] osgeo/gdal:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => [ 1/13] FROM docker.io/osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.6.3@sha256:398d5aca0ca88295c13ada87e0f382ed409dac13a952461187be72ce3c376513                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                            0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 106.80kB                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 2/13] RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y gnupg                                                                                      0.0s 
 => ERROR [ 3/13] RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C 
------
> [ 3/13] RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C:
#7 0.565 Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
#7 0.586 Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.sBrxtWnhQq/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
#7 10.62 gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C]: exit code: 2
```

[Note: I am using WINDOWS 11 Pro]

Does anybody have idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution.

I just changed

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
```

to

```
COPY select-path-frames/apt-key.txt ./
RUN cat ./apt-key.txt | apt-key add -
```

My `apt-key.txt` file contains the key of this version which was downloaded from here https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/